# RViz cannot display robot arm until I enable show robot collision

Tags: robotic-arm, ros, rviz

I followed the [tutorial](https://ros-planning.github.io/moveit_tutorials/doc/quickstart_in_rviz/quickstart_in_rviz_tutorial.html) to display a robot arm in RViz. However, Rviz displayed nothing until I enable the "show robot collision" feature in **MotionPlanning**-**Scene Robot**

Can anyone tell me how to fix this issue?

My OS: Ubuntu 20.04

ROS: ROS1 Noetic

When I followed the tutorial, what I got was just a ball
[image]

When I enable the "show robot collision" feature, I got a red robot_arm 3D model
[image]

This is the tutorial result. A white robot arm.
[image]

Comment: I solved this problem by downgrading Ubuntu to 18.04 and reinstalling ROS.  So, I  guess the issue was caused by "new rules". You have to provide more information about your robot arm so Rviz can display the whole model.

Answer (score 0):

The collision visualization is of simpler low polygon forms used for faster collision avoidance. What you're expecting to see and not seeing are the meshes for the visualization of the robot arm. To that end I don't know why they're not rendering, but it's likely that you are missing a dependency which is providing those meshes as resources. I would suggest double checking that you've installed all the prerequisite dependencies for that tutorial. And double check your environment setup.